# Hide IDM popup for downloading audio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I play an audio using the function below and it works fine:

```js
function sfxPlay(source) {
    return new Promise(resolve => { 
        const sfxAudio = new Audio(source);
        sfxAudio.play(); 
    });
}


document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    sfxPlay('https://freesound.org/data/previews/511/511749_9271295-lq.mp3');
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Play audio</button>
```

The issue is if user has IDM ( Internet Download Manager ) installed there is this annoying popup asking user to download the audio.

I want to hide this popup. [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JEbL.jpg ]

**Note: I don't want to prevent user from downloading the audio, instead I want to hide the IDM popup.**

**Note 2: I want this for end users not me, so it should be done with javascript not disabling IDM**

How to do this?

[image]